# Turn a string of HTML code into actual HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So imagine I received this string back from my server:

```
'<h1>hello everyone</h1>'
```

How can I turn this string into actual HTML that I can insert into my document?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
var response = '<h1>hello everyone</h1>';
document.getElementById('localContainer').innerHTML = response;
// or
document.write(response);
```

```html
<div id="localContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that doesn't work with HTML strings. I tried the link to the other post and tried it with div.insertAdjacentHTML and that worked